# Using Mkfs.xfs and setting the version information

Tags: linux, partition, xfs, mkfs

When I use mkfs.xfs it is not enabling NLINK.

I have another drive in the machine that is set up the exact what I need this drive setup and the only difference is NLINK on one and not on the other.  Is there anyway to use Mkfs.xfs with an option to tell it that I want NLINK enabled?

**xfs_db> version**  (What I need)

[0x20a4+0x0] = V4,NLINK,ALIGN,DIRV2

**xfs_db> version** (What it is)

[0x2084+0x0] = V4,ALIGN,DIRV2

Is there anyway to get them to match up?

Comment: Any difference between drives and type of content you are storing?

Comment: No, so I have an a DD of one drive to the other and it works perfectly, but then I cannot remove the corrupted data.   It works if I do that.  Unless there is a good way to format it after doing that?  and just remove the data without changing the partition.  rm -rf does not work on the corrupted data and its taking up 2GB on a 9 GB harddrive partition.

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to create the filesystem that doesn't ha
ve the NLINK bit set? Is this faulty filesystem created by dd?

If I understand this correctly, from the docs, XFS_SB_VERSION_NLINKBIT is set if any inodes use 32-bit di_nlink values.

For NLINK to not be set, no inodes would use a 32-bit di_nlink value, which would mean the filesystem is using v1 inodes.

Instead of using dd to copy the drive, you may want to look into xfs_copy.
For corrupted data, xfs_repair may be of use.

Which version of mkfs.xfs are you using? "mkfs.xfs -V"

Comment: mkfs.xfs -f /dev/sda5